# GitHub Actions: can I dynamically generate and run a child workflow?

Tags: gitlab-ci, github-actions

We are migrating from gitlab to github.

With gitlab pipelines I am checking the repository and [dynamically generating](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/parent_child_pipelines.html) a child pipeline with the actual jobs to run. This is easiest explained by the actual definition:

```yaml
stages:
    - bootstrap
    - run


    
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Bootstrap
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

bootstrap:
    stage: bootstrap
    # this will write the file jobs.yml to disk
    script: ./bootstrap.ps1

    artifacts:
        paths:
            - artifacts/jobs.yml



# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

run:
    stage: run
    trigger:
        include:
            - artifact: artifacts/jobs.yml
              job: bootstrap
        strategy: depend
```

Is there anything similar in github actions? I found that it's possible to dynamically generate a matrix, but that is not enough.

I need to run jobs that depend on each other and run in parallel/sequence.

Example:

[image]

This whole job graph is dynamically generated.

Here I'd have three stages where all the app jobs run in parallel, and the single deploy job waits for all app jobs to complete.

I also need to pass outputs from the app jobs to the deploy job, which also seems to not really work with a matrix: https://github.com/github-community/community/discussions/17245

> even if the output is set by multiple matrix variations of the job, only one is retained.

---

So, **actual question** is there a way to generate a workflow with multiple interdependent jobs on the fly and execute it, or is this something that just doesn't exist?

Comment: You can add dependencies between jobs by using the [`needs`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idneeds) field. But the workflow you would need to generate dynamically would be quite complicated, so I don't know if it's an option.

Comment: @GuiFalourd (How) Can I generate and run a workflow dynamically at all? The only thing I found was using a matrix and fromJson, but that's too restricted.

Comment: It's possible, but doesn't seem to be worth it. To do so you would have to create a workflow file through your first workflow run, commit it, then trigger it, and as the workflow will persist, you would also have to remove it afterwards if you don't plan to use it anymore... There might be another alternative instead of trying to do it that way.

Comment: Thank you, yeah you're right that's a bit inconvenient. Okay, I think I can solve it another way.

Comment: @LukasRieger could you please share you "another way"? I am looking for the same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can trigger multiple interdependet already exsiting workflows (on the fly). create in the bootstrap job a list of workflows names paired with the info if the workflow needs to be trigger or not.
And in the run job use this list to trigger the workflows.